# Is it possible to upgrade a second generation iPod Touch to iOS 4.3?

Tags: itunes, ios, ipod-touch

Suddenly a lot of my apps are not working on my iPod Touch 2nd gen.  Many of these are telling me that I need iOS 4.3 for them to work.

I've tried updating software in iTunes - but it says my current version 4.2 is the latest and there are no updates to install.

Any ideas?

Please answer

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

According to the incredibly useful [iOS support matrix v 2.0 (Winter 2012)](http://www.empiricalmagic.com/post/34832825209/ios-support-matrix-v2-0) done by Empirical Magic, the end of the line is running iOS 4.2.1 on an iPod touch (2nd generation).

[image]

Apps that target 4.3 or newer are just not going to run on that device unless the developers re-add support for that OS. Since the code set for that device is ARMv6 you can expect more and more apps to be dropping support as time goes by. Thankfully, what you have should keep running indefinitely, but updates will taper off.